# Does anyone knows how the filestream folder structure works?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find the database/table that these files correspond to. In the filestream data store they are always stored under two GUID.

Do they correspond to object id / column id? how to i translate back to know what tables and column they correspond to?

```
├───23617e6f-8c5d-4dba-9c99-6088a05a3e61
│   └───b644ba19-a592-4e1a-9d6f-e3914875a587
│           00000024-00000678-0009
│           00000024-00000688-0006
│
├───423da63b-0de5-4095-900f-2c5bfdbaf190
│   └───ccb1c3e9-8de5-4773-80fa-d9aa4a383b27
│
└───6e99731c-fc79-4859-a13e-ec2706e7ef60
    └───dd9465af-a05c-4636-ab73-c95be4a84254
            00000024-00000590-0009
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

```
SELECT
    [o].[name] AS [Table],
    [cp].[name] AS [Column],
    [p].[partition_number] AS [Partition],
    [r].[rsguid] AS [Rowset GUID],
    [rs].[colguid] AS [Column GUID]
FROM sys.sysrowsets [r] CROSS APPLY sys.sysrscols [rs]
JOIN sys.partitions [p]
    ON [rs].[rsid] = [p].[partition_id]
JOIN sys.objects [o]
    ON [o].[object_id] = [p].[object_id]
JOIN sys.syscolpars [cp]
    ON [cp].[colid] = [rs].[rscolid]
WHERE [rs].[colguid] IS NOT NULL
    AND [o].[object_id] = [cp].[id]
    AND [r].[rsguid] IS NOT NULL
    AND [r].[rowsetid] = [rs].[rsid];
GO
```